# Accuracy score of inceptionV3 tflite model is not good as of retrained_graph.pb file

Tags: tensorflow-lite

After converting retrained_graph.pb to tflite files Model score is not good.

we had followed the below steps to get tflite files :

Step1. Gathered the data images(.jpg) and put in the folder structure like

```
tf_files/cockroaches_photos/americancockroach/images

ex:tf_files/cockroaches_photos/americoncockroach/4.jpg
```

Step2 Before Training, Set the Image size and which architecture you need to train your model.(inceptionV3/MobileNet)

Set the Image size:

```
IMAGE_SIZE=299
```

Set the Architecture of inception_v3:

```
ARCHITECTURE="inception_v3"
```

Step3: Retrained the model with default 4000 epochs:

```
python -m scripts.retrain   --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks   --model_dir=tf_files/models/"${ARCHITECTURE}"   --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}"   --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb   --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt   --architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}"  --image_dir=tf_files/i_cockr_photos
```

In my case the Output at the end of line:

```
INFO: tensorflow:Final test accuracy = 93.2% (N=44)
```

Step4: Modify the scripts/label_image.py as followed below

```
input_height=299
input_width=299
input_layer=”Mul”
output_layer=”final_result”
```

Step5: Classifying an Image with retrained_graph.pb

```
python -m scripts.label_image --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --image=tf_files/i_cockr_photos/germancockroach/images.jpg
```

Output:
Evaluation time (1-image): 0.816s

germancockroach 0.88213
brownbandedcockroach 0.0920959
americancockroach 0.024512
australianspiderbeetle 0.000708872
greenhousecockroach 0.000419116

Step6: Optimized the model

```
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.optimize_for_inference   --input=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb   --output=tf_files/optimized_graph.pb --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF  --output_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --input_shape=1,299,299,3  --input_names="Mul" --output_names="final_result"
```

Step7: Verify the Optimized model with optimized_graph.pb:

```
python -m scripts.label_image --graph=tf_files/optimized_graph.pb --image=tf_files/i_cockr_photos/germancockroach/images.jpg
```

Evaluation time (1-image): 0.713s

```
germancockroach 0.882129
brownbandedcockroach 0.0920963
americancockroach 0.0245122
australianspiderbeetle 0.000708876
greenhousecockroach 0.000419114
```

Step8: Convert to Model to TFLite format:
(1)with retrained_graph.pb

```
toco  --input_file=/home/sudheer_sure/t_working/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb  --output_file=/home/sudheer_sure/t_working/tf
_files/t_c_labs_retrained_graph.lite  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF  --output_format=TFLITE  --input_shape=1,299,299,3 --input_array=Mul --output_array=final_result --inference_type=FLOAT --input_type=FLOAT
```

(2)with optimized_graph.pb

```
toco  --input_file=/home/sudheer_sure/t_working/tf_files/optimized_graph.pb  --output_file=/home/sudheer_sure/t_working/tf
_files/t_c_labs_optimized_graph.lite  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF  --output_format=TFLITE  --input_shape=1,299,299,3 --input_array=Mul --output_array=final_result --inference_type=FLOAT --input_type=FLOAT
```

(3)Convert tflite retrained_graph.pb using bazel & added of input_names & output_names parameters:

```
sudo bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco '--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF' '--input_file=/home/sudheer_sure/t_working/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb' '--output_format=TFLITE' '--output_file=/home/sudheer_sure/dummy/bazel_toco_retrain_inception_v3.lite' '--inference_type=FLOAT' '--inference_input_type=FLOAT' '--input_arrays=Mul' '--output_arrays=final_result' '--input_shapes=1,299,299,3' '--input_names=DecodeJpeg/contents' '--output_names=pool_3/_reshape'
```

(4) Convert tflite optimizedd_graph.pb using bazel & added of input_names & output_names parameters:

```
sudo bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco '--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF' '--input_file=/home/sudheer_sure/t_working/tf_files/optimized_graph.pb' '--output_format=TFLITE' '--output_file=/home/sudheer_sure/dummy/bazel_toco_object_inception_v3.lite' '--inference_type=FLOAT' '--inference_input_type=FLOAT' '--input_arrays=Mul' '--output_arrays=final_result' '--input_shapes=1,299,299,3' '--input_names=DecodeJpeg/contents' '--output_names=pool_3/_reshape'
```

Here you can compare the score that we are getting before converting to tflite file i.e. directly from retrained graph and after conversion to tflite file

Score from retarined_graph.pb :

```
americancockroach 0.814701

greenhousecockroach 0.157736

germancockroach 0.0224954

brownbandedcockroach 0.00405233

australianspiderbeetle 0.000568162
```

Score from TensorFlow .lite files :

```
australianspiderbeetle, 0.012658036

confusedflourbeetle, 0.013540811

americancockroach, 0.033697817
```

Please let me know what needs to be done to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the `applyFilter()` under `classifyFrame()` in `ImageClassifier.java` which smooth the numbers already. Try to remove it and check the output again. 
Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53483553/6081433) .